# retrieving data from mysql and output json from php

Tags: php, mysql, json, arduino

I am dumping json from [Arduino MCU](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560)  in the following format,

> {"live" : [{"location" : "Outdoor" , "temperatureInC" : "33.90" ,
>   "temperatureInF" : "93.02" , "dewPoint_in_Fahr" : "21.18" ,
>   "dewPoint_in_Cel" : "-6.01" , "heat_index__in_Fahr" : "87.17" ,
>   "heat_index_in_Cel" : "30.65" , "humidity":"7.40" , "UVSig":"131.44"}
>   , {"location" : "Drawing Room" , "temperatureInC" : "31.20" ,
>   "temperatureInF" : "88.16" , "dewPoint_in_Fahr" : "46.78" ,
>   "dewPoint_in_Cel" : "8.21" , "heat_index__in_Fahr" : "85.03" ,
>   "heat_index_in_Cel" : "29.46" , "humidity" : "24.00"}] , "pots" :
>   [{"soilMoist" : "118", "avgSoilMoist" :"125" }]}

this data is live and realtime, however my Arduino is also dumping to mysql server.

to which I want retrieve using php and display it in the frontend

with little knowledge of php I wrote below code that successfully dumps data in browser from mysql server:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "secret";
$dbname = "arduinoData";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT  timeStamp, out_temperature, out_humidity FROM sensorLog ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<br>Time: ". $row["timeStamp"]. "<br>Temperature: ". $row["out_temperature"]. "<br>Humidity: " . $row["out_humidity"] . "<$
     }
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

however this spits out only two 3 columns of table and not even correct json, I want to retrieve data from mysql using php and dump `json` in same format as I am getting from arduino live except just replacing the button `live` with `database`.

this will be useful if I want to go live or retrieve data from database in the frontend page on client side. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am novice in php.

Comment: You are only selecting 3 colums : " timeStamp, out_temperature, out_humidity " , I beleive you have two or more rows of data, So change your query to :  $sql = "SELECT  * FROM sensorLog ORDER BY timeStamp DESC";

Comment: providing your database schema would be useful , specially that your database schema does not seems to be like json format.

Comment: You'll need to load an array with the key and MySQL values and then transform it to JSON using `json_encode`. PHP Manual PHP:json_encode - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php. Another possibly helpful link - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_php_example.htm.

Comment: @HassanAhmed do you mean having MySQL table to have same column names as keys in json retrieved ?

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz not exactly, but i mean you are choosing fields from database that is not exists in your json, so will be hard to help without at least an illustrate for your schema;

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all the columns you need to select * instead of the 3 specific column names in your query. And to get a valid JSON object you only have to encode the results with the PHP ***json_encode*** function, as in the example below:

```
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM sensorLog ORDER BY timeStamp DESC LIMIT 1";
$result  = $conn->query($sql);

$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);
```

> **NOTE**:
>   You can always use json_decode to convert the JSON string back to the original results array.

Comment: I left this out; to get the same column names as in Arduino, you will have to select each column as the corresponding name of the Arduino field.

Comment: I think : `$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` is wrong.

Comment: Well, this is what i used and i tested with his code, and it worked. See [http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

He only has to get the column names right and that's it.

Comment: see my php code : http://pastebin.com/CpbQsRfg did I made any mistake ?

Comment: Great, that should work! Now you can test it live and see for yourself. Please update us if everything works fine after testing.

Comment: Okay that's good. But remember `$named_array = $result->fetch_assoc();` only worked because you needed only one specific row. Congratulations though :-)

Comment: Then what was your answer trying to pull ?

Comment: My answer pulls all rows returned by the query; and in your example my answer still pulls only one row because you used `limit 1`. So mine is only more convenient because you may not always want to select only one row. You get it?

Comment: I get the point but I attempted as per your answer it didn't worked. Never mind thanks for your time